# AlamofireImage is not deallacating the memory

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, alamofireimage

I am setting an image to `UITableViewCell` from [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) with the extension `af_setImageWithURL` that's work perfectly when I scroll it too fast the memory size is increased and **it does not decrease however I stop the scrolling**.

I am using in `UITableViewCell` class:

```
imgProduct.image = UIImage()
clearImageFromCache(imageURL)
let filter = AspectScaledToFillSizeFilter(size: imgProduct.frame.size)
imgProduct.af_setImageWithURL(imageURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(),filter: filter)
```

I have also tried `NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()` but no luck.

```
func clearImageFromCache(URL:NSURL) {
    let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL)

    let imageDownloader = UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader

    // Clear the URLRequest from the in-memory cache
    imageDownloader.imageCache?.removeImageForRequest(URLRequest, withAdditionalIdentifier: nil)

    // Clear the URLRequest from the on-disk cache
    imageDownloader.sessionManager.session.configuration.URLCache?.removeCachedResponseForRequest(URLRequest)
}
```

Here is the screenshot of memory debugging:

**Before:**

[image]

**After scrolling:**

[image]

**NOTE:- It works perfectly when I scroll without images.**

Comment: Are you running on simulator? - Check what happens when you use `Debug -> Simulate Memory Warning`

Comment: @WarrenBurton I am using iPhone 6 and iPad mini 4!, but Ok let me check!

Comment: Use the memory debugger. It should tell you why your images are not being discarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to deallocate the image**

```
imgProduct.image = nil
```

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani then try do this before you set image

imgProduct.image = nil

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani why do you need this line?
imgProduct.image = UIImage()

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani your memory leak because you call this method inside cell, you can create function and shared instance, and call this function in that shared object. In this way you reuse it, instead call new each time

Comment: Which method I have to call with shared?

Comment: Ok let me check!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155600/discussion-between-salman-ghumsani-and-maxkoriakin).